# VS Code colorize extension not working in javascript file

Tags: visual-studio-code, colorize

so I installed colorize extension into my vs code. Though the extension works in CSS files, it does not work in my javascript file. I use ChakraUI which means styling my code is usually within the javascript. I saw from the extension "how to install" that it is possible to style in a javascript file and all that should be done is to include "javascript" in the colorize.languages settings. I did this and it is still not working in my js file.

P.S: I am using the file extensions .jsx and .tsx

Edited: So I notice that if the file extension is js or ts it works but when I use jsx or tsx it doesn't. Does anybody know what I will write in the colorize.languages that will make the colorize extension work in a .jsx or .tsx file?

Comment: if you don't give a link to the extension you use we don't know if you use the old or forked version, and/or give the **full** name of the extension

Comment: if you modify one of its settings **show** the setting, not as an image but just text

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add the following code in your setting.json

```
"colorize.include": [
        
        "**/*.css",
        "**/*.scss",
        "**/*.sass",
        "**/*.less",
        "**/*.styl",
        "**/*.ts",
        "**/*.tsx",
        "**/*.js",
        "**/*.jsx"
    ]
```